# PyInstaller doesnt show print statements

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I tried making a .exe file from a simple python file

```
# hi.py
input("enter something")
print("hi")
```

It created an executable and when I ran it, it prompted me "enter something" and after hitting enter, it just exists the window. I tried doing

```
pyinstaller -F hi.py
```

and

```
pyinstaller --onefile hi.py
```

but both commands do not show the print statement. Is there any fix to that?

Comment: don't double click it. try to open a new cmd windows and run the exe using command line.or add  `input("press enter to exit")` at the end

Comment: That did the trick. However, im still wondering what's the difference between double clicking it and running it via terminal? Is there a way so that I can double click the exe (or a link to the exe)?

Comment: well, I dont know the internal either. the trick I'm using is `input("press enter to exit")` at the end.

Comment: try using auto-py-exe. That is what I use when converting to .exe files. Install it as well as pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

It runs and closes instantly, run it through a command line

```
<file>.exe
```

This way you will see the output